# complicated nested if statement

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am hoping that someone can modify my existing query and provide me the SQL for me to copy and paste based on my 2 conditions listed below.  Thank you very much in advance, Nathaniel

**condition#1**. compare the values of the following 3 fields and output the lowest value of the 3 fields (exlcuding null values):

"lowest list price"
"lowest price sold"
"lining_price_exception"

example: if "lowest list price" = 3 and "lowest price sold" = 7 and "lining_price_exception"  =null, then the output should be 3.

**conditon#2**. if the value in the field  "overide_price" is not null, then the field "overide_price" should replace the output from from condition #1. if the value in "overide_price" is null, then output the value from condition#1.

```
SELECT q.Part_ID, q.[lowest list price], q.[lowest price sold], 
       q.lining_price_exception, q.overide_price
FROM qry_to_determine_wmx_price_01 AS q;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be complicated enough for you. Here is tested SQL no need to define any VBA methods which meets both criteria:

```
Select q.Part_ID, 
           q.[lowest list price], 
           q.[lowest price sold], 
           q.lining_price_exception, 
           q.overide_price,
           NZ(q.overide_price,
                 IIf(q.[lowest list price]<q.[lowest price sold] OR ISNULL(q.[lowest price sold]),
                       IIf(q.[lowest list price]<q.lining_price_exception or ISNULL(q.lining_price_exception),
                             NZ(q.[lowest list price],"No valid Price listed"),
                             q.lining_price_exception
                          ),
                       IIf(q.[lowest price sold]<q.lining_price_exception or ISNULL(q.lining_price_exception),
                             NZ(q.[lowest price sold],"No valid Price listed"),
                             q.lining_price_exception
                          )
                    )
                 ) as Actual_Low_Price        
from qry_to_determine_wmx_price_01 as q;
```

Comment: Indeed, that's what the ISNULLs are for it was a pain... This is why I said your version is better if only because it's far easier to read! I tried to make mine readable, but there's only so much you can do.

Comment: Daniel, I prefer SQL because I dont know how to apply VBA. I ran your code and it has a slight bug,  that outputs "#Error" for all records where the field "lowest list price" is not null, but all of the other fields are null. would you be able to modfy your SQL to prevent this error?  please let me know if I should convert nulls to zeros (NZ function) in my data-source "qry_to_determine_wmx_price_01". Thank you very much nathaniel

Comment: Make sure all of the fields being compared are numbers in your table. This should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you will be running your query from within an Access session, you can use a custom VBA function to make this easier.

Testing the `MinValue()` function in the Immediate window ...

```
? MinValue(4, Null, 2)
 2 
? MinValue(Null, Null, 2)
 2 
? MinValue(Null, Null, Null)
Null
```

So you could tackle your **condition#1** in a query like this ...

```
SELECT
    MinValue(
        q.[lowest list price],
        q.[lowest price sold], 
        q.lining_price_exception
    ) AS lowest_value
qry_to_determine_wmx_price_01 AS q;
```

As for your **conditon#2**, I think the `Nz()` function would be useful.

```
Nz(q.overide_price, MinValue(q.[lowest list price], q.[lowest price sold],
q.lining_price_exception))
```

Basically that `Nz()` expression says "return `overide_price` if it's not Null, otherwise return the value from the `MinValue()` expression".

This is the function I mentioned.

```
Public Function MinValue(ParamArray pValues() As Variant) As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim iUbound As Long
    Dim varMin As Variant
    iUbound = UBound(pValues)
    varMin = Null
    For i = 0 To iUbound
        If Not IsNull(pValues(i)) Then
            If Not IsNull(varMin) Then
                If pValues(i) < varMin Then
                    varMin = pValues(i)
                End If
            Else
                varMin = pValues(i)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    MinValue = varMin
End Function
```

Comment: I admit, this is definitely a better solution. :-)